# Generate Alert message for @Html.Actionlink in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one ActionLink in view page like :-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Index", new { id="actedit"})
```

but i want to use this id in javascript like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#actedit").click(function () {
    alert("Working okay");
    $('#trdata *').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});

});
```

I just try to make it conent editable process using this actionlink id but i could not able to fetch the id from view page by using action link. I can get the id by using anchor link.. Is there any idea to get the id value from view to jquery..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a link to trigger some jQuery, you should just use `<a id="actedit" href="">Edit</a>` instead, as an action link will always redirect to that action.

EDIT: You still want to use an action link, here is the code needed to create the action link you want:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", null, new { id="actedit"})
```

However, as it is an ActionLink as soon as you click on it, it will redirect to that action. You will also need to supress that event in your javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#actedit").click(function (e) {
    alert("Working okay");
    $('#trdata *').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had work with anchor tag <a id="actedit" href="#">Edit</a> its working fine but need to know how to passing id values to jquery via @html.actionlink.

Comment: I would still argue that using an action link is wrong in this situation, but I have edited my answer to show you how to do so. 

All an action link is doing is generating the `<a href="Index" id="actedit">Edit</a>` for you, but filling in the href with the link to the specified action in that controller.